# Can more than one wallet receive fees?

Tags: spl-token

If we use the new Solana SPL Token-2022 program where you can add transfer fees to a token, can we set up more than one wallet to receive fees?

For example total of 4% fees

Wallet 1 gets 1%

Wallet 2 gets 1%

Wallet 3 gets 2%

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as answered and upvote it. Thank you :)) https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you can't divide transaction fees between multiple signers. Each `Transaction fee` is paid by `one signer` in Solana.

But If your transaction contains multiple instructions, you can extract the instructions and create atomic transactions (1 instruction). then have each one paid by a certain `signer`.

Comment: Do you/anyone have source code or any other examples we can look at to see how this can be done in practice?